# Adding an external jar library to Intellij IDEA

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea, jsoup

I'm having a silly problem : I'm trying to add the Jsoup library (which is just an external jar) to my android application developed in Intellij Idea and it seems and don't do it right .
I put the library in the libs folder , then I went in Project Structure -> modules and selected dependencies , select add global library , select attach source and click ok.

When I write code  it is able to automatically import classes  and to compile , but when running I get " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at the newer artifacts section.  Perhaps you don't add the JAR into your deployment properly.

UPDATE:

I'd like to update my answer based on lessons learned over the past six years since I first answered this question.

The best way to manage 3rd party JAR dependencies in Java projects is to learn Maven (my preference) or Gradle.  IntelliJ has terrific integration with both.

If you combine those with an enterprise repository like Nexus you'll have no problems.  Your dependencies and versions will be completely specified.  Conflicts will be identified for you.  Updates will be relatively simple.

Comment: To vague to be useful to anyone starting out with IntelliJ. Consider being more concrete/prescriptive.

Comment: @duffymo  What do you mean by, "perhaps you don't add the JAR into your deployment properly?"  Your sentence is poorly constructed and overall, your answer is a bit too vague.  Can you please elaborate on where in Artifacts section I should be looking?  I tried reading the documentation and creating an artifact according to the online directions but it didn't resolve any issues that I was encountering.  Unfortunately, stating that perhaps I'm loading the JAR file incorrectly isn't much assistance because it's just stating the overall problem, which is rather obvious... :-/

Answer (score 23):

- Copy the .jar file into your lib/ directory.
- Right click the new .jar in the lefthand file browser in IntelliJ / Android Studio
- Choose "Add as Library..."
- Voila!

Comment: As I'm new to Android and Java, can't understand what 'duffymo' says. But your help was very clear and great for me and my case. Thanks...

Comment: Thanks buddy, glad you thought so!

Comment: There is no Lib directory in my project.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, there should be a directory by default that holds any external ie third party source. If not, perhaps something to do with your project setup. If it's not named "Lib" I'm sure there's a similarly functioning directory there just with a different name. Good luck.

Comment: you may need to include the folder in project structure.  Try going to file -project structure - modules - choose module - sources tab - find libs folder - if red it's excluded, click exclude icon at top right to reinclude - click apply and ok - may need to click refresh/sync button.

Answer (score 1):

-Open the External Libraries node on the Left hand panel. 
-Select Open Library Settings
-Project structure dialogue opens up.
Select the Libraries.
Click the "+" to browse the file.

![add external jar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdqvM.png)

Comment: Where do I find "Open Library Settings"? I've looked in the right-click context menu and all the menus across the top of the screen...

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA 15 you can also access the Project Structure menu item from "File" item in the menu bar. Select Libraries from the list on the left. Click the "+" to browse the file, select it and you're done. It will be added to the "External Libraries" directory in your project.